# An eely function $\mu (n):\;\;\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {\mu (n) - \mu (k)} \right)} = 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations, recursion

Time ago, dealing with a generalization of the Stirling numbers, I stumbled on the following implicit recurrence
$$
\mu (n):\;\;\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {\mu (n) - \mu (k)} \right)}  = 1\quad \left| \matrix{
  \,0 \le n \in Z \hfill \cr 
  \,0 \le \mu (n) \in R \hfill \cr 
  \,\mu (0) = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Using a good CAS it is not difficult to compute the first few values and plot them

[image: Uniprod_1]

Clearly, the sequence is monotonically increasing, and its finite difference is monotonically decreasing *(1)*.

Such a regular behaviour leads me to expect that it might be extended over the reals and that
$\mu (x)$ might be expressible through a combination of conventional functions.

From time to time I am returning to this challenge with some inspiration for a new approach, but
the combination difference & product has frustrated all my attempts.
I couldn't even succeed to establish its asymptotic behaviour (now, thanks to @AMarino answer I know it's logarithmic) .

So I am asking for hints, suggestions.

*-- addendum  --*

Putting $\rho _{\,n,\,m}  = \mu _{\,n + 1}  - \mu _{\,m} $ , an alternative way to express the problem is
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \prod\limits_{0\,\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\rho _{\,n,\,k} }  = 1 \hfill \cr 
  \rho _{\,n,\,k}  - \rho _{\,n - 1,\,k}  = \mu _{\,n + 1}  - \mu _{\,n}  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
which means to find a family of functions whose product wrt $k$ is $1$
and whose difference wrt $n$ is constant, as shown

[image: Uniproduct_2]

My last tentative has been to take two discrete pmf's on the support $[0,n]$ and put
$$
\rho \left( {n,m} \right) = e^{\,h(n)\left( {p(m\,|n) - q(m\,|n)} \right)} 
$$
which by definition gives the unitary product, but cannot go  yet through keeping the difference constant.

*-- note 1 --*

That the difference is monotonically decreasing comes from being
$$
\eqalign{
  & \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {\mu (n) - \mu (k)} \right)}
  = \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {\mu (n) - \mu (n - 1) + \mu (n - 1) - \mu (k)} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {x + \left( {\mu (n - 1) - \mu (k)} \right)} \right)}
  = p_n (x)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  p_n (0) = 0 \hfill \cr 
  p_n (x) < p_{n + 1} (x)\quad \left| {\,0 < x} \right. \hfill \cr 
  1 = p_n (\mu (n) - \mu (n - 1)) < p_{n + 1} (\mu (n + 1) - \mu (n)) \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \mu (n + 1) - \mu (n) < \mu (n) - \mu (n - 1) \cr} 
$$
which tells the interesting fact that $\Delta \mu (n-1)$ comes as the root of $p_n(x)=1$, which in turn is added
to its zeros, shifting them to the left as to start from $0$ and making them the zeros of $p_{n+1}(x)$.

Comment: What makes this function "eely"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman: I called it so because many times I was thinking to hold it in my grasp, but ..remained with empty hands!

Comment: I opened [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118253/eely-function) to comment / discuss further

Answer (score 5):

This is only a partial answer.

If your claim is correct, i.e. differences are decreasing, then the sequence is sublogarithmic. Indeed, let $s(n) := \mu(n+1) -\mu(n) $. The recurrence relation, using the claim $s(j) > s(n)$ for $j<n$, rewrites as

$$ 1 = \prod_{k=0}^n (\sum_{j=k}^n s(j) ) > \prod_{k=0}^n (n-k+1) s(n) = (n+1)! s(n) ^{n+1} $$

Which implies that

$$ s(n) < \left ( \frac{1}{(n+1)! } \right ) ^{1/(n+1) }$$

The Stirling approximation can be written as $m! \approx (m/e) ^{m}$. Substituting we get that $s(n) < \frac{e}{n+1}$ . Thus we have

$$ \mu(n) = s(n-1) +\ldots+s(0) < $$
$$ e \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1} \approx e \log(n) $$

We also have a sort of converse to this. Suppose that for all n we have
$$(*) \ \ s(n) > \left ( \frac{1}{(n+2)! } \right ) ^{1/(n+2) }$$

That is, the sequence is also superlogarithmic. We want to show that differences are decreasing. Suppose that at some point $n$ we have for the first time that the difference increase, aka $s(n) \ge s(n-1) $. Then we get

$$ 1 = \prod_{k=0}^n (\sum_{j=k}^n s(j) ) \ge \prod_{k=0}^n (n-k+1) s(n-1) = (n+1)! s(n-1) ^{n+1} $$

From which we get, using again Stirling approximation, the opposite (*) inequality, yielding a contradiction.

This argument can be made precise with inequalities instead of plain Stirling approximation, but since it is not a strong result with respect to your requests, I think it's not worth. Hope it can inspire someone else for a more sophisticated approach :)

Edit. I have an approach for the lower bound. By substituting each factor with the biggest $s$ appearing we get a reversed inequality

$$ 1\le n s(0) \cdot  (n-1)s(1) \ldots 1 \cdot s(n-1) $$

Rearranging terms and taking the logarithms we get

$$ 0 \le \log ns(n-1) + \ldots +\log 1\cdot s(0) $$

Let us define
$$\sigma(n) := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0} ^{n-1} \log (j+1) s(j) $$
Equation above ensures that $\limsup \sigma(n) \ge 0$. Now the plot twist: by Stolz Cesaro the limsup of the general term is greater or equal than the average one, so that

$$ \limsup \log s(n) (n+1) \ge \limsup \sigma(n) \ge 0$$

Which implies that

$$ \limsup s(n) (n+1) \ge 1$$

Which provides a lower bound like estimate. If this can be refined to be a limit, than by summing over n we would get that $\mu(n) \ge \log(n) $ asymptilotically.

Comment: very interesting, thanks. Now there is an approach to bound the asymptotic

Comment: I added the proof that the difference is decreasing

Comment: That's very cool! Joint forces make the difference :D good team job man! I'm also convinced that the sequence is superlogarithmic but I can't show this.. I think a similar approach could work: we have to show a reverse bound like $s(n) > s(n-1) c_n$ to apply an argument similar to mine and obtain the other side of the inequality.

Comment: I saw now (didn't get notice on inbox) that you could find the lower bound as well: good job, thanks. I would ask, if you are interested, further help in fixing some other interesting properties

Comment: Hi, thanks. Notice that the lower bound proof is not complete, because there is a limsup that could be not a limit. However I think It should be convergent! If you want to investigate further properties, I suggest you ask more specific questions, whether here or in a separated post :D

Comment: thanks for the attention. Well, the core of the question is to find a nice expression for $\mu(n)$ and possibly $\mu(x)$

Comment: p.s.:  $\ln(n) < \mu(n) < e\, \ln(n)$ looks to work, although the fork is large.

Comment: Honestly I tried to put some logarithmic expressions, but they don't seem to satisfy the constraint on the nose. Can I ask you if your background makes you suspect that there should be such a closed expression? Usually showing that something does not have a closed expression in terms of known functions is very hard.

Comment: Well, clearly I cannot sustain that there should be a closed expression, I only suspect that it is too "smooth" for not having one. I added about my last and current attempt.

Comment: @G Cab: hi, just a random idea. I was reviewing the idea on how to generalize the n factorial, which resembles a bit what you want to do: jumping from a discrete recurrence to a smooth function in a nice way. Probably you know this is done by the Gamma function, which is an integral from zero to $\infty$ and the variable is plugged in as parameter in the integral. So now I am looking for an expression of the form $\int f_n(x) g(x) dx$ . Maybe using this on the two variate version is even easier?

Comment: Also, since we expect $\mu(n) $ to be logarithmic, I would search for an integral form of $\nu(n) = e^{\mu(n) }$. This has also the nice feature that, if we write $\nu(n) =\sum c_n^k \nu(k) $, the recurrence relation rewrites as $\sum \log \log c_n^k = 0$, which has a linear flavour - what we can get from integration by parts.

Comment: These coefficients also respects $c_{p}^q c_q^r = c_p^r$, so that the "new" coefficients respect $c_n^k = c_n^{n-1}c_{n-1}^k$. The log log relation is then secretly an equation just for one new variable $c_n^{n-1}$.

Comment: well, a) actually we can put the problem as to pass from $n! = n \cdot (n-1) \cdots $ to $1= \mu (n) \cdot (\mu (n) -\mu(1)) \cdots $   b) the approach with the $c_n^{k}$ looks promising, thanks. We'll talk more tomorrow on a chat I will open.

Comment: I went a bit deeper onto your suggestion for $\ni (n)$ but could not catch it.

Comment: me neither XD you are right this is very hard :)